# string between, php

Tags: php, string

as I am new to php, and after googling :) I still could not find what I wanted to do.

I have been able to find start and end position in string that i want to extract but most of the example use strings or characters or integers to get string between but I could not find string bewteen two positions.

For example:
  $string = "This is a test trying to extract";
  $pos1 = 9; $pos2 = 14;

Then I get lost. I need to get the text between position 9 and 14 of of the string.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$startIndex = min($pos1, $pos2);
$length = abs($pos1 - $pos2);

$between = substr($string, $startIndex, $length);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to extract part of a string. This works by setting the starting point and the length of what you want to extract.

So in your case this would be:

```
$string = substr($string,9,5); /* 5 comes from 14-9 */
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$string = "This is a test trying to extract";
$pos1 = 9;
$pos2 = 14;

$start = min($pos1, $pos2);
$length = abs($pos1 - $pos2);

echo substr($string, $start - 1, $length); // output 'a test'
?>
```

Comment: +1 Good catch, never depend on the user interface to validate the input

Comment: Is there a reason for the `- 1` after `$start` ?  Seems you'd pull data 1 left of where he wants.

Comment: The only reason I put the -1 is because as a newbie the OP may not have been aware of array indexes starting at 0. So she will have entered 1 as the starting position and received a message starting with 'h'. Maybe I was wrong to assume.